# Error FormGroup boolean

Tags: angular, primeng

En mi html tengo:

```
<form novalidate (ngSubmit)="save()" [formGroup]="form">
<label class="blueColorLabel">Name:</label>
<input class="form-control w100" formControlName="name" type="text" minlength="3">
<div *ngIf="form.controls['name'].invalid && (form.controls['name'].dirty || form.controls['name'].touched)" class="alert alert-danger pt10">
      <span *ngIf="form.controls['name'].errors.required" class="p-inline-message p-inline-message-error">Field is required</span>
      <span *ngIf="form.controls['name'].errors.minlength" class="p-inline-message p-inline-message-error">Must be at least 3 characters long.</span>
</div>

<p-checkbox formControlName="frozen" [binary]="true"></p-checkbox>
<p-button type="submit" label="Save"></p-button>
```

en mi .ts

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  name: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)] ],
  frozen: [false, Validators.required],
});

save() {
  console.log(this.form)
}
```

El valor en la consola me llega nulo, solo me llega true/false si hago click en el checkbox

Comment: Veo definido el `FormGroup` en tu código TS, pero no hay definido un elemento `<form>` del HTML que pertenece al componente de ese código TS, que es necesario para agregar el `FormGroup` que señalé al principio, y que también es necesario para que se sincronicen los dos atributos `formControlName` que estás usando en el HTML.

Comment: @cristiancajiaos perdon si que existe, lo añado en mi pregunta

Answer (score 0):

has probado a declarar explicitamente los FormControl?

```js
this.form = this.fb.group({
      name: new FormControl(null, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(3),
      ]),
      frozen: new FormControl(false, Validators.required),
});
```

Comment: tb lo hice pero me sigue llegando null